# I have to find the length of the string which can be display in single line according to device screen width in Xamarin forms(Android) app

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin-forms-4

There should only be one line of text displayed and multiple lines should be restricted. In cases where the string is long and going on the 2nd line, I need to trim it according to a particular logic.

I am working on android app using xamarin forms.

I know how to find the width of the device, but I can't figure out how to count the characters that will display on a single line.

Comment: What have you tried already? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: unless you are using a monospace font, the number of characters will vary depending on the actual text